# Can eclim be integrated with aptana?

Tags: aptana, eclim

I using vim as my primary editor for python/HTML/JS/CSS and heard of Eclim as a means to integrate code completion and other "advanced" IDE techniques into vim.

I tried to use ctags and other code completion techniques, but they don't really cut it as far as I could tell.

Therefore, I'm was thinking of using Eclim, but would prefer to use it with Aptana-Studio, since it pretty much contains everything I need (as opposed to Eclipse which will require me to install several plugins to get it to work the way I want it to).

Is there a way to integrate Eclim directly with Aptana? Is my best bet using Aptana as an Eclipse plugin?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to install Eclim as a plugin into Aptana Studio standalone. Download Eclim 1.6.3 installer from http://sourceforge.net/projects/eclim/files/eclim/1.6.3/ (1.7.x won't work yet since Aptana Studio standalone is 3.6) Point the installer to Aptana Studio installation folder and it will do the rest.

Another option is to download Eclipse Indigo (3.7) and install both Aptana Studio and Eclim as a plugins (same steps for Eclim as above though).

Regards,
Max

Comment: Thanks! I guess I failed to install eclim since I tried the latest version.

Comment: nearly a year on and this is still the case. Boom, correct answer!